# conditional CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, case

I have a table with the below structure:

```
CustID | Number 1  | Number 2 | Number 3  | Number 4
    1  | 072454584 |          | 017726593 | 
    2  |           |0125456852|           | 0125785448
```

I'm trying to do a query that selects the first number that is available, so if using customer ID 2 it would return only number 2, if there was a record with only number 4 present it would ignore 1,2,3. I've tried doing a case when statement but I cant seem to work out the logic.

Comment: I think you should better plan the structure of your tables

Comment: @Nadeem_MK I think you should read the question properly. "query that selects the first number that is available, so if using customer ID 2 it would return only number 2, if there was a record with only number 4 present it would ignore 1,2,3"

Comment: @Gavlaaa -as changing the structure is one thing that should always be considered on SQL questions you should mention you can't change it. Definitely don't abuse someone trying to help - It does not make others feel helpful

Comment: @Gavlaaa: no need to be rude, Andrey Gordeev was not really constructive but he's correct in saying that the model seems to be semi optimal. If you have columns `Number 1` - `Number N` you shoudld better normalize it and use a separate table instead of columns. That makes all queries simpler and far more efficient. It's also much more maintainable and less error-prone if you plan to add more columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have NULL values in those columns then use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT CUSTID, COALESCE(number1, number2, number3, number4)
```

Comment: Didn't have any nulls but easy to work round. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) which returns the first non-null value:

```
SELECT COALESCE([Number 1],[Number 2],[Number 3], [Number 4]) AS FirstNonNullNum
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE CustID = @paramID
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/737c5/4/0)</kbd>

However, your model seems to be semi optimal. If you have columns `Number 1` - `Number N` you shoudld better normalize it and use a separate table instead of columns. That makes all queries simpler and far more efficient. It's also much more maintainable and less error-prone if you plan to add more columns.